# Mini Project advice

Tags: java

I've decided to actually do some work outside class times to try and improve. So, I decided to make a little project that I thought would be pretty cool. However, I don't know how realistic I am being.

The idea is it defines peoples moods by what they say. It's only a small program just to help me improve. So my plan is for the program to detect generic words inputted by the user... so 'happy', 'sad' ect to determine their mood. Obviously in the real world this wouldn't be efficient, but as it's just for me to improve I thought it'd be cool.

Now,

I was thinking of creating two Strings happy & sad. These Strings would then somehow be ran when the user has typed in these generic words I am going to include. Is there any way to assign words to variables as such or am I completely going into the wrong direction ?

Cheers :D

Comment: `String[] words = {"happy", "sad"};`

Comment: Use arrays.  codeNinja's example shows how to do an array of strings.  You may find 2D arrays useful.

Comment: Uh are you trying to categorize words as happy or sad?

Comment: Ah I see. Makes sense an array of Strings. It's like if I read code I can understand I fairly well, but when it comes to applying it I'm terrible... explains my recent exam result = ( so I've gotta really improve

Comment: And yeah @Clark. Also, If I have variables declared and then use a constructor to say this.happy = h; ect. Why when I create a new method and return happy; it's ok but try returning h; and it doesn't detect h ? I thought that was the purpose of the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Associative Arrays http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array in your given language, they're arrays that contain key value pairs. So you could have the 'Happy' word as a key and the values as the generic words.

Then if the user types in a generic keyword, you could do a look up (this will be different depending on your language) of the Associative array, and find the Key ('Happy' or 'Sad') 'Associated' with that word.

Make sense?

Comment: In Java, you would use a `Map` along with _generics_.  A specific `Map` implementation to use would be `HashMap<String, Boolean> words = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();`.